# Token Error with ArcGIS Server 10.2.2

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2

I am using the ArPy example from esri sample. Script was working fine but then I updated my ArcGIS Server to 10.2.2 and I am getting this error: **Token Expired, Code: 498**. I have proper credentials as I am able to login to ArcGIS via Manager.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Example_Publish_service_definitions_listed_in_a_text_file/01540000061r000000/

Comment: What version had you been using previously? Did you regenerate the token after upgrade?

Comment: It was 10.2.1, will look into regenerating the token, thanks